# How do I automate a page whose id keeps changing but the title remains the same?

Tags: ruby, watir

We have a web application which has a list of reports, which I am trying to automate.

There is an option to view all these reports. When I open a report to view, there are some values I need to select to view it, which is where I am stuck.

The `id` used for these reports are generic. If the `id` for `<label>Application<lable>` is `<select id="id1" name="id[1]" class="valid">`, the same label in a different report will have a different `id`. How do I proceed from here?

Giving the tags of two sample reports:

First report:

```
<div>
 <label id="PackageID">
       Package ID <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input id="id_1__Name" name="id[1].Name" type="hidden" value="PackageID">
    <select id="id_1__SelectedValues" name="id[1].SelectedValues" class="valid">
  </div>
```

Second report:

```
<div>
 <label id="PackageID">
       Package ID <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input id="id_5__Name" name="id[5].Name" type="hidden" value="PackageID">
    <select id="id_5__SelectedValues" name="id[5].SelectedValues" class="valid">
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you share more of the html. There is likely a parent element that contains both the report name and the fields (or something that a user uses to differentiate the fields). You can use this parent element to differentiate the fields (rather than by the dynamic id). You can seen an [example of doing this in the Watirways book](https://leanpub.com/watirways/read#leanpub-auto-locate-an-element-based-on-its-ancestors).

Comment: I didn't get the question. What is the problem? What is your goal?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this suggestion is suitable for your scenario, but you could get the id with jQuery and store it in a hidden field:

```
var id = $('.className').attr('id');
```

or use control's [ClientID property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, to select proper value you just need

```
@browser.select_list(:id, "id_5__SelectedValues").set("3")
```